# Java JPA, setting transaction isolation level using an entity manager

Tags: java, jpa, transactions

I'm trying to set a transaction isolation level for the connection associated with a given entity manager (`TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE` etc.).

I have scoured the internet for a solution and found a few. However, none of them seem to work.

When I try to do the following :

```
EntityManagerFactory emfactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("BankingPU");
public EntityManager em = emfactory.createEntityManager();

java.sql.Connection connection = (java.sql.Connection) em.getDelegate();               
connection.setTransactionIsolation(TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE);
```

I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: 
org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl cannot be cast to java.sql.Connection
```

When I do

```
EntityManagerFactory emfactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("BankingPU");
public EntityManager em = emfactory.createEntityManager();

java.sql.Connection connection = em.unwrap(java.sql.Connection.class);
```

The value stored to `connection` is `null`.

I ran the following in order to find out more:

```
Object obj = em.getDelegate();
```

The class type stored in `obj` is `org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl`

Edit: (oops, guess I could have told that from the exception)

Edit2:

I have managed to obtain the session (i think) by calling :

```
 Session session = ((EntityManagerImpl) em).getSession();
```

However, neither the `connection()`, nor the `DoWork()` methods are present in it.

Any idea how to follow up on this and set the transaction isolation level?

Answer (score 4):

JPA API does not have transaction (TX) isolation level management API. So it is not possible do it via entity manager.
If you want to use the same entity manager than you need, as it already mentioned in Neil Stockton comment, your JPA provider specific code to get JDBC access for changing TX isolation level.
Adam Bien almost answered on your question at his [blog post](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/how_to_deal_with_transaction).
*Isolation Levels can be set on java.sql.Connection level. In a Java EE environment isolation levels can be configured on Data Source / Connection Pool (see e.g. Glassfish).*

As workaround, if you want use only JPA API, you may create in your application server the several data sources for the same database with required isolation level.
However you need to understand that you will have the several 1st level caches (in different entity managers) and you should manage your entities state in appropriate way.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution:

```
    emfactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("BankingPU");
    em = emfactory.createEntityManager();

    Session session = ((EntityManagerImpl) em).getSession();
    DatabaseLogin databaseLogin = (DatabaseLogin) session.getDatasourceLogin();
    databaseLogin.setTransactionIsolation(DatabaseLogin.TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE);
```

Comment: you're going to mention that you are seemingly using HIBERNATE, because what you post would be totally useless to any other JPA implementation, so this "answer" is not an answer for JPA, but explicitly for HIBERNATE only