# What is the reason for javax.transaction.Transactional cannot specify the isolation level?

Tags: java, transactions

What is the reason for `javax.transaction.Transactional` cannot specify the isolation level while it is possible with springframework Transactional? How can one manage the isolation level when using standard Transactional annotation?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/37398148/2568649

Comment: Thanks, this gives better understanding of the situation

Answer (score -1):

If you look at the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/transaction/Transactional.html#value--) you will see that you **CAN** specify the transaction isolation levels for `javax.transaction.Transactional`.

It can be done like this ...

```
@Transactional(value = Transactional.TxType.NEVER)
void test() {
  ... JPA code goes here ...
}
```

You can find the list of support `Transactional.TxType` values [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/transaction/Transactional.TxType.html). They are almost the same as in Spring.

Does this resolve your problem ?

Comment: I don't think that is about transaction isolation level, I think it relates to whether a transaction has to exist etc when the annotated method is invoked. Transaction isolation levels are vendor specific I believe so I can understand why JPA wouldn't deal with  that, I suspect Spring help by defining some generic isolation levels that get mapped under the covers according to driver but I haven't checked the source to see

Comment: Reading through the link I shared a bit more carefully, there is a more fundamental issue - tx isolation is specified at connection level so defining different levels on different methods would require mapping those to specific connections

Comment: Thank you for the link to javadoc but as you can see the attribute it describes controls the propagation type (whether a bean method is to be executed within a transaction context). Spring definitely has analog [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html) - propagation attribute but the question was about the _isolation_ one which can have pretty standard values - **READ_COMMITTED** **REPEATABLE_READ** etc. So the answer does not resolve the problem.